# Convert a given property-access to chained string

Tags: c#, function, lambda, expression

I'm trying to write an extension-method to retrieve a property-path from a given `LambdaExpression`.

I want to be able to call it like

> var path = ((Event e) => e.Address.City.Name).ToChainedPath();

which would return `Address.City.Name` as `string` separated by `.`.

Currently my extension looks like this

```
public static string ToChainedPath<TSource, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr, char separator = '.')
{
    MemberExpression me;

    switch (expr.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
        case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            var ue = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
            me = ue?.Operand as MemberExpression;
            break;
        default:
            me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            break;
    }

    var propertyNames = new List<string>();

    while (me != null)
    {
        propertyNames.Add(me.Member.Name);
        me = me.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }

    propertyNames.Reverse();

    return string.Join(separator, propertyNames);
}
```

Which is working fine when used like

```
Expression<Func<Event, string>> expression = e => e.Address.City.Name;
var propertyChain = expression.ToChainedPath();
```

But this does not work for what I want because `(Event e) => e.Address.City.Name` is `Func<Event, string>` and not `Expression<Func<Event,string>>`.
I already tried to convert the `Func` to an `Expression` but nothing helped so far.

I also changed the extension to extend `Func` instead of `Expression` but then I loose the `Body`.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Your exact requirement is not possible. A few similar syntaxes are possible: `((Expression<Func<Event, string>>)(e => e.Address.City.Name)).ToChainedPath()` or `GetChainedPath(e => e.Address.City.Name)`.

Comment: @Sweeper I was afraid that this is not possible. So I will go with the second approach and leaving the extension behind. Thanks for clarification. If you post an answer I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda expression itself does not have a type (See the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#anonymous-function-expressions)), so the compiler won't know where to find `ToChainedPath` if you just do:

```
((Event e) => e.Address.City.Name).ToChainedPath();
```

You haven't given it any type information about what the lambda expression should be converted to (a delegate type? an expression type?). Therefore, this exact syntax is not possible.

One other way that you *can* give type information, is with a method parameter.

```
EnclosingClass.GetChainedPath(e => e.Address.City.Name);
```

If the compiler can resolve what `GetChainedPath` is, it will know that it has a parameter of type `Expression<Func<Event, string>>`:

```
public static string GetChainedPath<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr, char separator = '.')
```

and so it knows what type the lambda should be converted to.

If you want this to be extra concise (omitting `EnclosingClass.`), you can do a [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) for `GetChainedPath`.

```
using static YourNamespace.EnclosingClass;
```

Comment: Neat one with the `using static`. Didn't know about this feature till now